# How to declare an array of checkboxes in android

Tags: android, arrays, checkbox

I have googled this question but cannot find a simple or specific enough answer to it:
Could any experienced programmer help me...?

I have an array of 10 checkboxes in a custom dialog called dialog1.

```
public class DigitsActivity extends Activity {
...
CheckBox[] ckbDigits = new CheckBox[10];
...


public void SelectDigit1(){  // method which opens the custom dialog

Context context=DigitsActivity.this;
final Dialog dialog1 = new Dialog(context);
...
for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++){
  ckbDigits[k] = (CheckBox) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.ckbDigits[k]);
}
...
}
```

I am getting multiple errors at the line

```
ckbDigits[k] = ...
```

I tried also :

```
ckbDigits[] = (CheckBox) dialog1.findViewById(R.id.ckbDigits[]);
```

but it doesn't work either...

Could anybody tell me how to declare an array of checkboxes ?

Thanks.

Comment: How have you declared such checkboxes on the XML?

Comment: Did you try ArrayList of checkBox?

Answer (score 1):

Declare  `CheckBox chk[];`

Then do this way

```
  chk=new CheckBox[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            chk[i] = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
            chk[i].setChecked(true);
           // whatever operations
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. have you called "setContentView" before trying to find the views?
2. have you initialized the array of ids ?
3. what's this : "R.id.ckbDigits[]" ?
4. in any case , i would suggest naming the ids as something like "checkbox0" , "checkbox1" ,... , and then find them by using getIdentifier (like [this](http://steven.bitsetters.com/2007/11/27/accessing-android-resources-by-name-at-runtime/)) , in order to make the initialization of the ids easier . you could make it stop when it didn't find the id that it has searched for.

Answer (score -1):

You must to declare a new vector of CheckBox like this

for example :

```
public class Test{
   static int ckbDigits[]={id.ckbDigits0,id.ckbDigits1,id.ckbDigits2,id.ckbDigits3,
    id.ckbDigits4
    id.ckbDigits5,id.ckbDigits6,id.ckbDigits7,id.ckbDigits8,id.ckbDigits9};

}
```

After you make something like this in your code

```
for (int k = 0; k <= 9; k++){
  ckbDigits[k] = (CheckBox) dialog1.findViewById(Test.ckbDigits[k]);
}
```

Comment: You're declaring `ckbDigits` as an `int []`, and then trying to stuff checkboxes into it. Are you sure?

Comment: yes this is buggy code. array of CheckBox must be declared before mapping it with the ids